# Storing users in a comment model in Sinatra and Mongoid

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid

There is sparse documentation on how to go about this. I have a comment model which has a field that stores the user who created the comment, and the user the comment is directed at.

I figured there are two ways of doing this:

```
class Comment
      include Mongoid::Document

      field :from, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId    # The user who created the comment
      field :to, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId      # The user the comment is directed at
      field :details, type: String
```

-OR-

```
class Comment
      field Mongoid::Document

      belongs_to :user    # The user who created the comment

      field :to, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId      # The user the comment is directed at
      field :details, type: String
```

Are there any benefits to doing it one way or another? Or are these two the same? Or is there a better way? Using Mongoid and Sinatra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way you have works fine, but if you do it that way and want the user information you will need to add helper methods to use the id to pull the user.

The second is part way there but I would do:

```
belongs_to :from_user, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :to_user, class_name: 'User'
```

That way you can do `comment.from_user` and `comment.to_user` and get the actual users. The ids are still there just not explicitly called out but produced from the belongs to.

All of that being said, since this is mongo and a document database, if there is specific info from the user you need for the comment I might be inclined to just embed the info you need right in the comment so you don't have to do a relation.